# Using a normal function f(x) in python

Tags: python

I want to use a function f(x) in python. Something like ax^2 + bx + c (polynomials). I want to do that using a for loop and a list. This is what I have so far:

```
def f(a,x):
    for i in range (0, len(a)):
        i = ([a]*x**i)
    print (i)
```

for example: when I fill in `f([5,2,3],5)` I have to get:
3*5^0 + 2*5^1 + 5*5^2. Does somebody know how I can change my code so the output will be the result of that polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You just need to add a running sum, and you need to select individual numbers from `a`

```
 def f(a,x):
     running = 0
     for i in range (0, len(a)):
         running += a[-1-i]*x**i
     return running
```

Comment: You're great!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

use a [`generator expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) with `enumerate`

```
>>> sum(data*x**index for index, data in enumerate(reversed(a)))
138
```

You can use this comprehension in you `func` like this :

```
def f(a,x):
    print(sum(data*x**index for index, data in enumerate(reversed(a))))    
>>> f([5,2,3],5)    
138
```

EDITED : More optimized version suggested by @Paul Panzer

Comment: It doesn't really matter but you can optimize this by (1) using a generator expression instead of a list comp (just leave out the square brackets). (2) using `reversed` instead of the slice copy: `sum(data*x**index for index, data in enumerate(reversed(a)))`

Answer (score 0):

Using loop

```
def f(a,x):
    j = 0
    num = 0
    for val in a[::-1]:#Reverse a i.e [3,2,5]
        num = num + val*x**j 
        j = j + 1
    print(num)  

f([5,2,3],5)
```

**Output**

```
138
```